# Does the conjugate transpose of invertible covariance matrix is the matrix itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I am new to linear algebra and have a problem, suppose a covariance matrix is given by $\Sigma$, which is invertible and can be written as $$\Sigma=U \Lambda U^*$$ where $U$ is a rotation matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix. I know that covariance matrix transpose is equal to the matrix itself, but does the same hold for conjugate transpose in case of invertible covariance matrix?

Comment: Since $U$ is the rotation matrix, it is unitary. So the answer is yes

Comment: if I am right than doing conjugate transpose will give $$(K_z)^*=(U diag U^*)^*$$ which gives $$U^* diag^* U$$ $$diag^*=diag $$ so you mean to say that $$U^*=U$$ then why we need to write $$K_z=(U diag U^*) and not K_z=(U diag U)$$

Comment: First, please don't use this notation. Write $K_z=U\Sigma U^*$ which is nicer and more readable (upon saying that $\Sigma$ is diagonal). Second, it is sufficient for $\Sigma$ to be real, which is true for a positive definite matrix. Third, take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

Comment: But there U and V are two different rotation matrix, and here we have both same. Sorry but I still can't get you.

Comment: If you are not in a hurry, I'll post an answer right when I get home

Comment: yes please, I am totally confused now.

Comment: Covariance matrices have real entries. Conjugation does not matter.

Comment: @Wintermute I don't understand,  vector $v$ which is complex multiplied against $v^*$ can definitely result in a covariance matrix with non-real entries...? If you weren't trying to say that covariance matrices can only have real entries, then I have no clue what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for arbitrary matrices with appropriate dimensions,
$$ (ABC)^\star = C^\star B^\star A^\star $$

(I added this because you made the mistake in the comment and seemingly used $(ABC)^\star = A^\star B^\star C^\star$ which is incorrect)

therefore in particular:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
(U\Lambda U^\star)^\star &=& (U^\star)^\star \Lambda^\star U^\star 
&=& U\Lambda U^\star
\end{eqnarray}$$

since the singular values are real and thus $\Lambda=\Lambda^\star$.

Note: as was commented, a covariance matrix has real entries so the hermitian transpose is actually just simply the transpose and you're back on the result that you knew from before.